# "Win" tooltip appears under Surface Pro 3 pen - how do I stop it from showing up?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface

Occasionally, when I use the pen with the keyboard folded underneath my Surface Pro 3, a tooltip labeled "Win" will show up under the pen's pointer.

This tooltip doesn't show up under my finger when I use it directly on the screen, nor does it appear under the mouse. It only appears underneath by the pen's crosshairs, and has the formatting of the tooltip.

Currently, the way I get rid of this is by folding the keyboard back over to the other side, folding the Surface out so that it stands upright, then press the windows key twice. This clears the tooltip, but is disruptive and annoying, particularly when I'm taking notes in class.

How do I stop the "Win" tooltip from appearing under my pen?

Comment: I suspect the reason your getting this icon is because your folding the keyboard underneath your device.

Comment: @Ramhound It's supposed to do that.

Comment: I have a Surface Pro 3.  I have the keyboard.  It does not seem natural to fold the keyboard behind the surface and place it on a table causing weight to be placed on the keys of the keyboard itself.  Of course I also have never seen a "Win" tooltip in any of the applications I have used with the pen with.

Comment: @Ramhound Flip the keyboard upside-down and reattach it. It should fold over properly.

Comment: @Ramhound [Yeah, it's definitely supposed to do this.](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/hardware-and-drivers/type-cover#Fold)